# External react component cannot see React.Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The external React component says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined` when I link as npm package.

I link a package in `package.json` as `"react-mapbox": "https://github.com/varya/react-mapbox.git"`. Then I use it in code

```
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import MapBox from "react-mapbox";

render(
  <div>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <MapBox />
  </div>
  ,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

But nothing works, I get that error. The full repo is here https://github.com/varya/react-mapbox-test I made a small example to illustrate.

The `react-mapbox` package is my own, maybe I build it wrongly? This is its repo [https://github.com/varya/react-mapbox](https://github.com/varya/react-mapbox/tree/b8a503d63cbfd3c7e236147e00e140b8418552f9)
I built it with webpack, like that [https://github.com/varya/react-mapbox/blob/master/webpack.config.js](https://github.com/varya/react-mapbox/blob/b8a503d63cbfd3c7e236147e00e140b8418552f9/webpack.config.js) As I suppose, this build does not include react package assuming that this will be at the project which link it. But the component still do not see react object.

**UPD**

I added `import React from 'react';` as @aulizko suggested, but this only provided React object onto a page. It still was not visible for the component.

To fix this I had to provide this changes https://github.com/varya/react-mapbox/commit/2687d66025aaa84553a79850aa8686e88f1f39d9
I required `react` in the code of the component as well.
And I have to build with Babel. For some reason the webpack build gives the same error even if `react` is required. I created a branch to illustrate this https://github.com/varya/react-mapbox/tree/webpack Now I'm happy with Babel, but with this branch you can see what's wrong with webpack if interested.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably bundling your module as UMD which is causing the bundle to utilized a global `React` variable which doesn't exist in the consumer app. You need to export the bundle as a CommonJS or AMD module using https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget. Simple add `libraryTarget: 'commonjs2` or `libraryTarget: 'amd'` to the `output` key in the webpack config and make sure you are importing `react` in your component.

Answer (score 2):

I added `import React from 'react';` as @aulizko suggested, but this only provided React object onto a page. It still was not visible for the component.

To fix this I had to provide this changes https://github.com/varya/react-mapbox/commit/2687d66025aaa84553a79850aa8686e88f1f39d9
I required `react` in the code of the component as well.
And I have to build with Babel. For some reason the webpack build gives the same error even if `react` is required. I created a branch to illustrate this https://github.com/varya/react-mapbox/tree/webpack Now I'm happy with Babel, but with this branch you can see what's wrong with webpack if interested.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that the jsx-code that you see in your editor is not the code that will be executed by node or browser.

If you look into code that are generated by the babel, you'll see something like this:

```js
(0, _reactDom.render)(React.createElement(
  'div',
  null,
  React.createElement(
    'h1',
    null,
    'Hello, world!'
  ),
  React.createElement(_reactMapbox2['default'], null)
), document.getElementById('example'));
```

So as you can see it uses `React` constant under the hood.

You need to explicitely import `React` if you want to use jsx-code.

Add something like this in your code and it'll work:

```js
import React from 'react'; // <!--- add this!!!

import {render} from 'react-dom';

import MapBox from "react-mapbox";

// the rest of your code goes here...
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. This did not help. I resolved differently, I'll write an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import React's `Component` it this way:

```
import {Component} from 'react';
```

or even:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
```